# How do I encourage fellow riders not to yell in residential areas early in the morning?

Tags: etiquette

How do I encourage fellow riders not to yell in residential areas during early morning rides?

Comment: Are these people that you are riding in a group with? If so, a brief chat before you set off would probably do the trick.

Comment: Lead by example perhaps?  If you want to talk to someone, get close, face them, and pitch your voice lower and slower, and enunciate the words.

Comment: Another option is to ride in non-residential areas - meet up on the edge and go out of town for the loop.   Or make the residential parts a sprint so noone's chatting!

Comment: Much more information is required. Are you part of the group, what's the purpose of the group, is it in fact one group or just a series of individuals etc

Comment: @KDeclined What are they yelling? If it's safety related then it's tricky. If it's about last night's escapades ...

Comment: What do you mean by "yell"?  What are they yelling and how loud it it?  How big is the group, and are they yelling loud enough to be heard by the entire group, or just the few nearby riders?  And how early is "early morning"?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a club or organized ride contact the organizer and let him/her know the problem.  Usually there will be a communication mechanism that they can use to inform riders of the problem and corrective action. If no action is taken, and it is a huge problem, you can go one level up to the sponsors or a higher governing body (clubs are usually members of a larger cycling associations).  Usually sponsors or governing bodies don't want bad behavior associated with their respective brands, and will put pressure on the club or organization to quickly rectify the problem.

If it is an informal ride there will usually be a social media page (e.g., Facebook) used for communication (how else can you brag about the beating you laid down on everyone last ride).  You can use this to bring up your issue to "members".  If no action is taken, your next steps aren't as clear, but there are always option if you are creative (e.g., public shaming).

How far you want to go really depends how big of an issue it is to you.  For a  bit of rowdiness I would personally not go as far as I have outlined (i.e., I would just contact organizers), but I would for more dangerous behavior (e.g., chasing Strava segments on shared bike/walking pathways).